# How to remove header from CSV file using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and I have a requirement to remove header from csv file and then write into parquet format file using scala.

I am trying this but how do I remove the header:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("path")
```

Can someone please help on this.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Hi @GuruStron Thanks for the response. Its not working when i used like below                   spark.read.format("CSV").option("header","true").load("path"). The code is not working . Do you need to import anything?

Comment: Do you have any exception/build error? "is not working" does not say much.

Comment: Thank you. Its resolved now with option("header","true")